# Carfter:how to publish crafter site to react js

Tags: crafter-cms

Hi team i am following the https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.1/getting-started/your-first-website.html .so is it possible to publish this to react js .
also we have use the existing blueprint .how we can create the site from scratch .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are example React blueprints:

- https://github.com/craftercms/commercetools-blueprint
- https://github.com/craftercms/video-center-blueprint
- https://github.com/craftercms/wordify-blueprint/tree/react

You'll need to also understand the SPA configuration, see the docs: https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.1/site-administrators/engine/engine-site-configuration.html?highlight=spa

To start something from scratch, use the built-in Empty Blueprint.

Comment: suppose we use the blueprint of html5.will it be possible to publish that into react js . if yes then how  it converts the whole html site to react js

Comment: Crafter doesn't care if your site is HTML5, React, Angular, Vue, or other technology. It will work regardless. Converting your site from HTML5 to React is not related to Crafter. I suggest you read up on React and find the right tutorial to help you. You can then carry that app to Crafter to make it editable.